# java8 hierarchy data json parsing and store in mongodb in flat format

Tags: java, mongodb, java-8

I have json of 3 hierarchy which I want to store in mongodb. I want to store the data in flat format so that id could be generated for all the levels. Below is the json. each level data should store individually and when I get the data , I want the data in same relation. Please suggest how it can be achieved.

```
{
  "data":[
  {
  "countryId":"1",
  "countryName":"USA",
  "cityList":[
    {
      "cityId": "11",
      "cityName": "NY"
      "userList": [
    {
    "userId": "111",
    "userName": "user1"
    },
    {
      "userId": "112",
      "userName": "user2"
    }
  ]
    },{
      "cityId":"12",
      "cityName":"AC"
       "userList": [
    {
      "userId": "121",
      "userName": "user3"
    },
    {
      "userId": "122",
      "userName": "user4"
    }
  ]
    }
  ]
}
]
```

}

I want to store this data as mentioned below and should get the data in same hierarchy while retrieving

```
countryid countryname
cityid cityname
userid username
```

Comment: "when I get the data , I want the data in same relation"?

Comment: yes same relation and hierarchy. all are list country, city and user